# count children in Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to count all the children (Enonce) from each sources that are in my Firebase database.

This is the Firebase structure:

[image]

How can I count the childs "Enonce" from each sources ( Source 1 ; Source 2 ; .... ; ....)

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database API is quite well documented. Did you try anything already based on that? If so, can you edit your question to [show the code that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.